# App not published on Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

recently i am publish a gmail gadget on google app marketplace. **my listing is perfect but my gadget is not work fine 100%.** my gadget reade the mail 
signature if mail does not have a signature than it will not working .
   GAM  Technical Specialist respond back to me a mail =>

I'm sorry to hear that you're running into some technical difficulties. Unfortunately, I am only responsible for testing the applications to make sure they meet the Google App Marketplace listing requirements.

i could not understand what is the exact problem what type of **technical difficulties** they talking about. is  there any criteria to gadget working.
                                                              thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, solving this problem is likely beyond the powers of the StackOverflow readership.

Comment: Genrally Google is going down in my opinion. Not much of documentation, no help at all, only problems and problems. My application wasn't published for 24 hours without any errors and I can't find help anywhere.